# branchの運用について

Tags: git, git-flow

Git(GitHub)で、以下の様なリモートブランチで作業していたとします。

master
　　--develop
　　　　--branchA
　　　　--branchB
　　　　--branchC

通常の運用では、各ブランチの開発が終わったらdevelopにマージし、ステージングで確認した後にmasterにマージして本番リリースとなりますが、以下の様な状況が発生した場合、どうするのが効率的でしょうか。

- branchCだけを再優先でリリースしなければならなくなった
- 既にbranchAはdevelopにマージ済みだが、ステージングで未確認のため本番リリースはできない
- branchBはリモートにPush済かつPullRequest発行済でレビュー中のため、まだdevelopにはマージしていない

branchCをリリースするためにbranchAの確認を急いでbranchAとCを同時にリリースする、と言うのはナシで、あくまで先にbranchCのみリリースしたいです。

また、例のようにマージ済みのブランチが1つだけならまだいいですが、実際は複数あります。

何かいい方法があったら教えていただけますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

※Gitの仕組みをキチンと理解してないで無謀なことを言ってしまえば、branchCの親をdevelopからmasterに変えてしまうようなことができれば、hotfix的に扱えて理想的なんですが…(^-^;

Answer (score 5):

develop/master/topic ブランチの概念を持ち出しているということは、 [git flow](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/) のワークフローを想定しているのだと思います。

branchC を HotFix 扱いして、 master へマージしてはどうでしょうか。

---

git flow 的に HotFix 扱いするのなら、具体的な作業は次のようになるかと思います。

- branchC を develop ではなく、 master から派生させる形で rebase する。
  (`git rebase --onto` などが使えるかと)
- master--branchC の形にしてから、 master へマージする。
- 新たな master を HotFix としてリリースする
- (develop が置いていかれてるので) branchC を develop にマージする

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

developから派生させたbranchCを直接masterにマージできるなら、それがベストなのですが、「HotFix 扱いして、 master へマージ」と仰られているのは、それができる、ということですか？

Comment: 今回どういう状況になっているかはわかりませんが、branchCを切り出す前に何かdevelopにマージされていると、それも併せてmasterにマージされてしまいますね。

Comment: なるほど、 `git rebase --onto` ですね。
今ざっとググってみたのですが、パッと理解できるほど単純な仕様ではなかったので、勉強して試してみます。

Answer (score 2):

Gitにおいてブランチの親子関係は管理されていません。基本的にどこかで分岐した2つのブランチは互いにマージが可能ですから、branchCをmasterにマージすることはできます。ただこの場合、masterとbranchCが分岐した時点からbranchCまでの修正が全てmasterに適用されることになるので、

1. （前回のdevelop→masterのマージ）
2. developからbranchXを切り出し
3. branchXの実装が終わったのでdevelopにマージ
4. developからbranchA,B,Cを切り出し
5. branchAをdevelopにマージ
6. （branchCの変更だけをmasterに適用したい！！）

このような場合、branchCを切り出した後にマージされたbranchAが巻き込まれることはありませんが、切り出す前にマージされていたbranchXは既にbranchCの歴史の一部になっているため、一緒にmasterにマージされてしまいます。

これを避けるには、「masterに対してbranchCの変更だけを含む」コミットを作成する必要があります。

例えば `git rebase --onto` を使うと、developとbranchCが分岐した時点から現在のbranchCまでの各コミットを、masterを起点に作成しなおすといった作業が行えます。

- [実践 git rebase --onto - あらびき日記](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/a_bicky/20130210/1360504520)
- [Git - リベース](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v1/Git-%E3%81%AE%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD-%E3%83%AA%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9#%E3%81%95%E3%82%89%E3%81%AB%E8%88%88%E5%91%B3%E6%B7%B1%E3%81%84%E3%83%AA%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9)

単純なrebaseと同様に、現在のbranchCは失われますから、作業を始める時点のbranchCにtagを打つなり、リポジトリのバックアップを取るなりしておき、何かあった場合に戻せるようにしておくとよいでしょう。

Comment: なるほど、 `git rebase --onto` ですね。参考となるサイトのご提示もありがとうございます。なかなか複雑なようなので、ちょっと勉強して試してみます。

Answer (score 0):

branchAのマージコミットをrevertし、branchCをマージするのはいかがでしょうか。

branchCのマージ後、revert branchAを行ったコミットをrevertすることを忘れなければ、目的を達成できるかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。その方法は思い付いていたのですが、rebertするマージコミットの数が複数あると大変なことになってしまうので、できれば避けたいな、と思いまして…